# hide "add", "change", "delete" actions in djaongo admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a piecce of code like this:

```
class PlatformEnvInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PlatformEnv
    extra = 1
    classes = ['collapse']
    fields = ('environment',)
```

My PlatformEnv Model looks like this:

```
class PlatformEnv(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    ...
    environment =  models.ForeignKey(Environment, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Environment_ID', blank=True, null=True)
```

When the `PlatformEnvInLin` is shown now, you can select an `environment` via dropdown. But next to the dropdown there are buttons displayed to add, change or delete a environment. How can I hide these buttons?

Comment: So you want these to be readonly then, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by overriding the `formfield_for_dbfield` method.

```
class PlatformEnvInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PlatformEnv
    extra = 1
    classes = ['collapse']
    fields = ('environment',)

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        formfield = super().formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == 'environment':
            formfield.widget.can_add_related = False
            formfield.widget.can_change_related = False
            formfield.widget.can_delete_related = False
       return formfield
```